# Persistir histórico de entidades (objetos) usando MongoDB

Tags: java, postgresql, spring, mongodb

Tenho a seguinte entidade (diminuída em relação a entidade real):

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name = "produtoSequence", sequenceName = "sequenceproduto")
public class Produto {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "produtoSequence")
    private long id;
    
    private String nome;
    
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(nullable = true)
    private Date dataExclusao;
    
    private String categoria;

    //Getters e setters .....
```

Agora precisaria incluir uma outra entidade, que se referirá a um histórico. Esse histórico vai basicamente guardar informações do que acontece com o produto. Um log nesse caso não seria o suficiente, pois preciso tirar algumas métricas a partir desse histórico.

Um exemplo de histórico: um produto foi excluído, um histórico de exclusão do produto será criado, ou um novo produto foi adicionado, então um histórico de inclusão de produto será criado.

Decidi usar NoSQL para guardar essas informações, em especial o MongoDB, pois os dados são salvos em JSON, e não possuem um padrão que devo seguir (tabelas que aparecem em todas as consultas, caso precise de um novo dado, preciso inserir uma nova coluna). Isso, porque os históricos as vezes vão possuir dados diferentes dependendo do histórico salvo.

Exemplos de JSONs que representariam o histórico.

Histórico de criação do produto:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "produto": {
            "id": 15,
            "nome": "Máquina de lavar XPTO2000",
            "categoria": "Máquinas de lavar"
        },
    "dataCriacao": "11/06/2021",
    "categoriaHistorico": "Criação de produto"
}
```

Histórico de mudança de categoria:

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "produto": {
            "id": 15,
            "nome": "Máquina de lavar XPTO2000",
            "categoria": "Linha branca"
        },
    "categoriaAnterior": "Máquinas de lavar",
    "categoriaNova": "Linha Branca",
    "categoriaHistorico": "Alteração de categoria do produto"
}
```

Essa falta de padrão vai me ajudar muito a desenvolver, mas como construiria uma model para o Histórico que se comunicasse com a model de produtos? Se fosse SQL para SQL seria algo do tipo (abaixo) usando `JoinColumn` e fetch, mas lidando com SQL para NoSQL, não encontrei nenhuma anotação que faça essa conversão ou até mesmo uma integração entre os dois bancos.

```
 public class Historico {
     @Id
     private long id;
    
     @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
     @JoinColumn(name = "PRODUTO", referencedColumnName = "ID", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "HISTORICO_PRODUTO_ID_FK"))
     private Produto produto;
    
     @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
     private Date dataCriacao = new Date();
     //Getters e setters......
```

Como eu poderia salvar diversos "layouts" de histórico? Pensei em, no backend, escrever uma interface que contenham os atributos que serão usados em todos os históricos, e escrever implementações que tenham os atributos únicos, mas não sei se existe essa possibilidade. Isso está errado? Se não for isso, penso em uma classe gigantesca que iria crescer conforme novos históricos fossem criados, o que seria impossível de escalar.

Answer (score 0):

### MongoDB como escolha

> Como construiria uma model para o Histórico que se comunicasse com a model de produtos?

A ideia do `MongoDB` é boa, ao meu ver. A comunicação de um banco com o outro seria gravando o `id` do postgres no mongo.
Eu vejo o MongoDB como um bom banco para dar manutenção no sistema pois fica muito fácil de abstrair a ideia que está implementada.

Pensei em um `service` específico para o mongo, bem como um `repository`. Você recebe nesse service o id do postgres para fazer a consulta de histórico no mongo.

### Exemplos de Objetos de Histórico

Eu pensei em algo assim..

```js
{ 
    version: 1,
    id_relacional: 10,
    author: "joaosilva",
    when: new Date('06 07 2021'),
    created: 1,
    fields: {id: 5, name: "raquete de tenis", price: 450}
},
{ 
    version: 2,
    id_relacional: 10,
    author: "luisduarte",
    when: new Date('06 07 2021'),
    updated: 1,
    fields: {price: 400} -- o preço mudou para 400
},
{ 
    version: 3,
    id_relacional: 10,
    author: "luisduarte",
    when: new Date('06 10 2021'),
    updated: 1,
    fields: {name: "Raquete de tenis amarela e verde"} -- mudou o nome
},
{ 
    version: 4,
    id_relacional: 10,
    author: "fulanodetal",
    when: new Date('06 15 2021'),
    updated: 1,
    fields: {description: "A raquete é legal, bonita etc"} -- adicionou description
}
```

Eu considerei que o importante é você ter mapeado quais campos estão modificando.

### Inserts reais no MongoDB para teste:

```
db.history.insertOne({ 
    version: 1,
    id_relacional: 10,
    author: "joaosilva",
    when: new Date('06 07 2021'),
    created: 1,
    fields: {id: 5, name: "raquete de tenis", price: 450}
})
db.history.insertOne({ 
    version: 2,
    id_relacional: 10,
    author: "luisduarte",
    when: new Date('06 07 2021'),
    updated: 1,
    fields: {price: 400}
})
db.history.insertOne({ 
    version: 3,
    id_relacional: 10,
    author: "luisduarte",
    when: new Date('06 10 2021'),
    updated: 1,
    fields: {name: "Raquete de tenis amarela e verde"}
})

db.history.insertOne({ 
    version: 4,
    id_relacional: 10,
    author: "fulanodetal",
    when: new Date('06 15 2021'),
    updated: 1,
    fields: {description: "A raquete é legal, bonita etc"}
})
```

### Possíveis consultas no histórico

Obter todas o histórico do produto de `id_relacional` (id no banco postgres) = `10`

```js
db.history.find({id_relacional: 10})
```

Obter alterações do produto de `id_relacional = 10` e `author = fulanodetal`:

```js
db.history.find({id_relacional: 10, author: "fulanodetal"})
```

Modificações após 10/06/2021:

```js
db.history.find({id_relacional: 10, when: {$gt : new Date('2021 06 10')} })
```

Alterações no campo descrição desse produto:

```js
db.history.find({id_relacional: 10, "fields.description" : {$exists: true} })
```

Depois de elaborar a resposta eu penso que seria interessante acrescentar a hora no campo `when` porque o horário de quando foi feita a modificação seria importante.

Se essa solução não atender, explique os motivos porque vejo essa demanda constantemente e acho que podemos fazer boas discussões sobre ela.